# Pattern attribute in Angular (hard-coded version works, dynamic not)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An input should follow a pattern (e.g. `name` that is unique). I've written a custom directive to validate the input.

```
validationApp.directive('validationUrl', function($http, $parse){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      var queryParams = $parse(attrs['validationAttrs'])(scope);

      var validate = function() {
        //$http.get( attrs['validationUrl'], {params: $parse(attrs['validationAttrs'])(scope)} )
        //.success(function ( data, status, headers, config ) {

        data = {
          isValid: ($parse(attrs['ngModel'])(scope)=='Bob'?false:true)
        }; //fake response

        if ( data.isValid ) {
          elem[0].pattern = '^.*$';
        } else {
          elem[0].pattern = '^(?!^' + $parse(attrs['ngModel'])(scope) + '$).*$';
        }
        //})
        //.error(function ( data, status, headers, config ) {
        //  console.log('GET failed. Error status: ' + status);
        //});
      };

      scope.$watch(attrs['ngModel'], function (newVal, oldVal) {
        validate();
      });

    }
  }
});
```

This directive seems to work and Chrome's inspector tells me the input element ends up being rendered as

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name"
data-validation-url="http://example.com/validate/"
pattern="^(?!^Bob$).*$">
```

but Angular keeps this input as `ng-valid` no matter what.

Then, when I enter the input in the form as a hard-coded version (exactly as above), and enter "Bob", the hard-coded input switches to `ng-invalid`.

[Plunker demonstrates the issue.](http://plnkr.co/edit/5oIZ8Wbjj4wme5aPNNZ7?p=preview) (*Name 2* is hard-coded.)

What am I missing?

Comment: You should build your own validator and not miss-use the `ng-pattern` validator. If you get the controller of the ngModel you can set the state via the $setValidity function yourself. See the [documentation](http://www.benlesh.com/2012/12/angular-js-custom-validation-via.html)

Comment: I can't quite understand from your question what the expected behavior is vs. what you get. Instead of showing what works (but not what you wanted), describe exactly and clearly what you want. It is quite possible that you are not approaching this issue with validation incorrectly, so instead of dealing with bugs in your, let's understand what you are after

Comment: @Michael, I think I'll have to go that way, thanks for the link!

Comment: @NewDev, My use case is I need to check whether given serial number for a device already exists in the backend. If it does, user may not proceed and I'm planning to use a pattern validation to enforce this.

Comment: @jsruok, so you need an async validator - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators, instead of messing around with patterns. In fact, the example there is very close to what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NewDev's comments were helpful and I ended up with the following approach that incorporates async validation and patterns.

```
app.directive('validationUrl', function($http, $parse, $q){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$asyncValidators.customValidation = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                var params = [];
                params.value = value;

                return $http.get(attrs['validationUrl'], {params: params } )
                .then(function resolved(response) { 

                    if (response.data.isValid) {
                        elem[0].pattern = '^.*$';
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        elem[0].pattern = '^(?!^' + value + '$).*$';
                        return $q.reject('exists');                     
                    }

                });
            };

    }
  }
});
```

Thanks to patterns the focus is moved to first invalid field of the form (default web browser behavior).